# delete all incoming links to specified module with dxl

Tags: ibm-doors

Something went wrong I got no error but links are not deleted.

```
Link l

Object o

for o in document current Module do
{    
   for l in all ((o) <- ("/GMH/test4")) do 
   {
       void delete(Link l)
   }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, please add some details

Comment: I would like to delete all incoming links that comes from another modules to "/GMH/test4" module. @TonyRanieri

Answer (score 1):

I think here is the solution it works on my code. It is deleting links from a module to another one!

void deleteLinksFromSSS(string moduleName)
{

```
for tgtObject in document current Module do
{

    Object o = tgtObject
    Object t
    Link l

    for l in o -> "*" do
    {
        t = target(l)
        t <- o
        delete l
    }
    flushDeletions
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Despite how it may appear, links are actually stored in the 'outgoing' object side.

In the code you've provided, you are scanning for each incoming link, then deleting the link- but that doesn't actually do anything, because the link 'lives' on the other side of the transaction. You need to grab the link information, then go to the object where the link originates and delete from there.

Part of this will be making sure the module that contains that object is open in edit mode. There are examples of this code in the reference guide.

Comment: I think you identify the problem, I have to handle links first before deleting process. @Balthos